# Parallel execution of Bash commands

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have a Bash script that has a loop inside of which there is a Bash command that calls another Bash script which in turn calls Python scripts.

Each of these bash commands within the loops could be run independently from each other. When I later run it on an actual dataset, it takes some time to execute each command. Therefore, I would like to take advantage and parallelize this part of the script.

I spent a few days going over options in Bash that do parallel execution, while also giving me the option to choose the number of cores that I want to parallelize the code such that I wont flood the server. After looking for options the  GNU, `xargs -P` seemed to me the most reasonable, since I do not have to have a specific Bash version and it will work without installing extra libraries. However I am having difficulties making it work, even though it seems straight forward.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts i:t: option
do
case "${option}"
in
    i) in_f=${OPTARG};;
    t) n_threads=${OPTARG};;
esac
done    

START=$(date +%s)
class_file=$in_f
classes=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./$class_file))
rm -r tree_matches.txt
n="${#classes[@]}"
for i in $(seq 0  $n);
   do
     for j in $(seq $((i+1)) $((n-1)));
         do
            echo ${classes[i]}"    "${classes[j]} >> tree_matches.txt
         done
   done
col1=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./tree_matches.txt ))
col2=( $(awk '{print $2}' ./tree_matches.txt ))


printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads sh myFunction.sh -1 ${classes[k]} -2 ${classes[k]}

n_pairs="${#col1[@]}"

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "Exec time $DIFF seconds"
```

You can ignore the initial two nested loops, I just pasted the entire script for completeness. The part that is going to be parallelized is the 4th line of code counting from the end of the script:

```
printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads sh myFunction.sh -1 ${classes[k]} -2 ${classes[k]}
```

This will loop over all pairs which is in my case 1275 in total and will ideally execute `myFunction.sh` in parallel with the specified number of threads using the variable `$n_threads`.

However, I am doing something wrong because the iterator `k` in that line is not indexing my two arrays `${classes[k]}` and `${classes[k]}`.

The loop keeps iterating 1275 times but it only indexes the first element of both arrays when I echo them. I later changed that line to this for troubleshooting:

```
printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads echo "index" k
```

It is actually incrementing the value of `k` each time it loops, however when I change that line to this:

```
printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads echo "index" "$((k))"
```

it is printing out 0, 1275 times as the value for `k`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I actually have two vectors that are the same sizes and are input for `myFunction.sh` script. I just want an integer index to be able to index them at the same time and call my function with those two values that are indexed from those two vectors. I modified my code as follows based on your suggestion:

```
 for x in {0..10};
    do
        printf "%d\0" "$x"; done| xargs -0 -I @@ -P $n_threads sh markerGenes2TreeMatch.sh -1 ${col1[@@]}-2 ${col2[@@]}
```

however now when I execute the code I get the following error:

```
@@: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "@@")
```

I guess this index `@@` is still in string format. I just want integer indices to be generated by as I loop and can execute this command in parallel.

Comment: I'm not sure why your last command doesn't work, but notice that `-I` implies `-L 1`, i.e., only one line if input will be processed at a time.

Comment: `k` can only be incremented by `xargs` if it sees it! `${classes[k]}` is expanded by the inital script

Comment: Right, I think the problem is the order of evaluation. `$(( ... ))` is handled by the shell before `xargs` gets to see it, that's why `$(( {} ))` (or whatever you use as the argument to `-I`) doesn't work. You might have to use `bash -c` in your `xargs` command, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line in question:

```
printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads sh myFunction.sh -1 ${classes[k]} -2 ${classes[k]}
```

`${classes[k]}` will be expanded by the shell (to nothing most likely), before xargs has a chance to see it.

Perhaps you could reorder to:

```
for x in {0..1275}; do printf "%s\0" "${classes[$x]}"; done |\
xargs -0 -I @@ -P $n_threads sh myFunction.sh -1 @@ -2 @@
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error again, actually I have two vectors that are input to myFunction.sh these two vectors are of the same size and I can use one index value per command execution to call that function

Comment: you could replace `sh` with `echo` and check the expected value is being passed in. Are you sure `classes` holds valid data?

Comment: its actually two vectors, col1 & col2, I updated my main post to clarify this.

Comment: okay I fianlly figured it out... I simplified myFunction.sh script such that now it takes one argument and then it splits (cuts) the line into two using a comma as the delimiter. I followed your suggested structure and its working fine. Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This line isn't working as you think it is:

```
printf "%s\0" {0..1275} | xargs -0 -I k -P $n_threads sh myFunction.sh -1 ${classes[k]} -2 ${classes[k]}
```

What happens is that BASH will first expand things like `$n_threads` and `${classes[k]}` into strings and then calls `xargs`. Btw. `${classes[k]}` is always `""` since the key `"k"` isn't in the array `classes`. Try `${classes[$k]}`; then BASH will substitute the variable `k` first, then use the result to look up a value in `classes`.

Maybe a better approach would be write the values from `classes` into a file and use that as input for `xargs`. You may have to change `myFunction.sh` to accept a single argument (= one line of input) and take it apart in the script.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you could probably do:

```
classes=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./$class_file))
parallel markerGenes2TreeMatch.sh -1 {=1 'if($arg[1] ge $arg[2]) { skip() }' =} -2 {2} ::: ${classes[@]} ::: ${classes[@]}
```

or:

```
parallel --plus markerGenes2TreeMatch.sh -1 {1choose_k} -2 {2choose_k} ::: ${classes[@]} ::: ${classes[@]}
```

Then you can skip the whole generation of tree_match.txt, and $col1/$col2.

Use `parallel --embed` to include GNU Parallel directly in your script, so you do not have external dependencies.